# Config Nexus-IQ to use .pfx Certificate

Tags: ssl, nexus, pfx, sonatype

Ahoi guys!

The setup.

Nexus-IQ running on a Windows server, as a service, using the "clm-jsw".
I was trying to enable secured connection to the server, but i have pfx file, and i would like to know how i can use that in the config.yml so that server will load it and enable SSL.

the file should be something like that:

applicationConnectors:

```
- type: https
  port: 8443
```

What parameter shall be (if any), so that server take the pfx file?

TY

Comment: For future notice, IQ is a licensed product so you could have filed a support ticket for direct assistance.

Comment: That thought lingered in my mind, yet past experience led me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it !
This is the solution.
.pfx extension can be renamed to .p12 
As they are the type.

After that just use this in the Config.yml:

applicationConnectors:

```
- type: https
  keyStorePath: 'C:\Nexus-IQ\Certs\file.p12'
  keyStorePassword: yourpassword
  port: 8443
```